# Write through mapStore into database

Tags: java, hazelcast

I'm using Hazelcast mapStore to persist the data into Database.

Here is my code..

```
@Component
@SpringAware
public class DataMapStore implements MapStore<String, String> {

    @Autowired
    DataTblRepository dataTableRepo;
    

    @Override
    public void store(String key, String value) {
        dataTableRepo.save(String, String);
        
    }

  //remaining unimplemented methods come here
```

Here when I perform the **map.put(String,String)**

I'm getting this error

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-11-10T11:51:31.279+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Cannot invoke \"com.repository.DataTblRepository.save(String, String)\" because \"this.dataTableRepo\" is null",
    "path": "
}
```

Here is my repository

```
@Repository
public class DataTblRepositoryImpl implements DataTblRepository {
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Override
    public void save(){
//query logic to save in data
}
```

the above logic is working fine if I directly persist the data without using the MapStore..

Here is my DataTblRepository

```
@Repository
public interface DataTblRepository {

    void save(String value1, String value2);
}
```

Comment: Could you please attach code with your DataTblRepository?

Comment: Hi Andrian.. I have updated the question please check..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to instantiate object(Jdbc template) inside Hazelcast Map store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64792712/how-to-instantiate-objectjdbc-template-inside-hazelcast-map-store)